# Unable to launch the URL in robot framework

Tags: python, selenium, robotframework, selenium2library

Unable to launch the URL in robot framework. Browser window is opening and URL is also entered in address bar after that showing error message like "Unable to connect". Can anyone help me on this. Please give the instructions to setup the robot framework. Im using intelliJ Idea for run the robot framework.

[image]

Comment: can you get to that URL in a browser that you've opened manually?

Comment: Is there a Proxy required for normal browsing?

Comment: @BryanOakley When you open the same URL in any browser. Its working fine.

Comment: @A.Kootstra No proxy required for normal browsing.